# mqtt_client does not publish immediately

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, mqtt, iot

I am trying a trivial networking application where I have multiple nodes communicating using the publish subscribe model in `paho-mqtt (mosquitto)` in python.

The use case I want to model is a node has a certain job it needs to perform and it should acknowledge the receipt of a request to perform the job, and if the requesting node does not receive the acknowledgement in a certain time, it resubmits the request.

I start performing the job in the method designated for `on_message` event of `mqtt_client`

I have a following sort of code in my `on_message` method

```
# mqtt_client is the client object
# Job represents the job I need to start
# mqtt_topic is the topic the requester listens
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
  request = msg.payload
  if "PERFORM" in request:
    mqtt_client.publish(mqtt_topic, "ACK", 2, False)
    job = Job()
    job.dispatch()
```

The job definitely requires an arbitrarily long time to complete.
The problem I am facing is that the "ACK" message is not sent immediately by the `mqtt_client` before starting the job, and it waits to be send until the job has finished. I tried publishing the "ACK" and dispatching the job on a different threads but ended up with same results.

Now because the requester thinks the request has timed out every time, I enter a loop of request and job dispatches. 
I wanted to know if there is any way that I can have the "ACK" publish complete before I start with the job.

Comment: This is a dupe of the linked question, `job.dispatch()` needs to run on a separate thread and not block the mqtt network loop.

Comment: I tried to search for similar questions but couldn't find one. Thanks for pointing out.